Calculate the VaR of a 3 asset portfolio
How do we solve this problem?

I know that i'm supposed to build a variance/covariance matrix and then do the square root of the total variance. But i don't know why the FX is included in the correlation when its not in the portfolio

Because just as you cannot add apples and oranges, you cannot add dollars and euros.

I know i'm supposed to convert every asset's currency in euro. i just don't know what i'm supposed to do with the correlation of the Eur/Usd change rate

Hint: If $X$ is the exchange rate and $S$ the asset (for example a stock), then what is the standard deviation, or variance, of $\Delta(XS)/XS$ where $\Delta$ means change over a time period?

It would be more convenient for readers to read and answer if you put as much of your question as possible including the tables in text.

Hint: if you own 100 shares of Nvidia, and ceteris paribus i) USD depreciates 1% versus EUR ii) USD-denominated Nvidia share price drops 10%, then what would your losses be under each scenario?
